# Javascript Prototype General Enquries and Assign Id by Array Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, prototype

I am trying to learn how to work with javascripts prototype, I am only getting into it now. Please Excuse me if I ask ridiculously stupid questions

I just have a few pre-questions:

1. Is it worth learning? I mean it looks like a structured/clean
   approach to me?
2. Do/should you use this with jQuery this?
3. is there any major problems or reason not to use it and why isn't it commonly used or am i just slow?

Actual Question:

I have the following code:

```
var BudgetSection = function BudgetSection(name ) {
    this.id = "";
    this.name = name;
    this.monthlyTotal = 0.00;
    this.yearlyTotal = 0.00;
    this.subTotal = 0.00;
    this.lineItems = [];
};

BudgetSection.prototype.calculateSubTotal = function() {
    this.subTotal = ((12 * this.monthlyTotal) + this.yearlyTotal);
};

function BudgetLineItem(name) {
    this.id = "";
    this.name = name;
    this.monthlyAmount = 0.00;
    this.yearlyAmount = 0.00;
}

BudgetLineItem.prototype = {
    totalAmount : function() {
        var result = ((12 * this.monthlyAmount) + this.yearlyAmount);
    return result;
    }
};

var budgetSections = [];

section = new BudgetSection("test1");
section.lineItems.push(new BudgetLineItem('sub'));
section.lineItems.push(new BudgetLineItem('sub2'));
section.lineItems.push(new BudgetLineItem('sub3'));
budgetSections.push(section);

section = new BudgetSection("test2");
section.lineItems.push(new BudgetLineItem('sub'));
section.lineItems.push(new BudgetLineItem('sub2'));
section.lineItems.push(new BudgetLineItem('sub3'));
budgetSections.push(section);

section = new BudgetSection("test3");
section.lineItems.push(new BudgetLineItem('sub'));
section.lineItems.push(new BudgetLineItem('sub2'));
section.lineItems.push(new BudgetLineItem('sub3'));
budgetSections.push(section);

// first iterate through budgetSections
for ( var t = 0; t < budgetSections.length; t++) {
    var sec = budgetSections[t];
    console.log(sec);
// iterate through each section's lineItems 
    for (var q = 0; q< budgetSections[t].lineItems.length ; q++) {
        var li = budgetSections[t].lineItems[q];
    console.log(li);
    }
}
```

the first BudgetSection "test1" is at index 0 in the budgetSections array. how can i assign the id to "section_".

And then also how can i set the id of BudgetLineItem like so: `lineItemRow_<section_index><lineitem_index>`

Also finally n the for loop what would be the best way to generate html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally never use the `new` keyword if I can avoid it and do pure prototype-based programming with `Object.create`. Here's a simple example. I create a prototype-object called `rectangle` and then create an object called `myRectangle` which inherits from `rectangle`.

```
var rectangle = {
  init: function( x, y, width, height ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  },
  move: function( x, y ) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
  }
};

var myRectangle = Object.create( rectangle );
myRectangle.init( 0, 0, 2, 4 );
myRectangle.move( 3, 5 );
```

To explain in more depth what happens here, `Object.create` makes a new object with a specified prototype. When we access a property on an object (like `init` or `move`), it first checks the object itself. If it can't find it there, it moves up to the object's prototype and checks there. If it's not there, it checks the prototype's prototype, and keeps going up the prototype chain until it finds it.

When we call a function on an object (`myRectangle.init()`), `this` inside the function refers to that object, *even if the function definition is actually on the prototype*. This is called delegation - an object can delegate its responsibilities to its prototype.

A more class-like way to do this is:

```
function Rectangle( x, y, width, height ) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}

Rectangle.prototype.move = function( x, y ) {
  this.x +=x;
  this.y +=y;
};

var myRectangle = new Rectangle( 0, 0, 2, 4 );
myRectangle.move( 3, 5 );
```

The problem is when we need to do a deeper inheritance hierarchy:

```
function Parent() {
  /* expensive and possibly side-effect inducing initialization */
}

Parent.prototype.parentMethod = function() {};

function Child() {}

Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

We have to initialize a `Parent` object when all we really want is to set the `Child` prototype to an object based on `Parent.prototype`. Another option is:

```
Child.prototype = Object.create( Parent.prototype );
```

But now we've got this confusing, convoluted mess of prototype-based and class-based code. Personally, I like this instead:

```
var parent = {
  parentMethod: function() {}
};

// Using underscore for stylistic reasons
var child = _.extend( Object.create( parent ), {
  childMethod: function() {}
});

var instance = Object.create( child );
instance.parentMethod();
instance.childMethod();
```

No `new` keyword needed. No fake class system. "Objects inherit from objects. What could be more object-oriented than that?"

So what's the catch? `Object.create` is slow. If you're creating lots of objects, it's better to use `new`. You can still use `Object.create` to set up the prototype chain, but we'll have to wait a bit for browsers to optimize it enough for lots of instantiation.

Comment: The new keyword is there because the only way to use prototype before Object.create is to use constructor function to create instances. What is _.extend? need add a dependency to a a library just to set up inheritance? With inheritance it is desirable to re use Parent constructor because you inherit when Child __is__ a Parent. When you don't want to re run the constructor then you can use a mix in.

Comment: Like I said in the comment, I use underscore there for stylistic reasons. You can do the same thing without it: `var child = Object.create( parent ); child.childMethod = function() {};`. There are many cases when you don't want to use the call super pattern, and there are lots of resources out there explaining why. Nothing in my example prevents using the call super pattern - I don't use it in the `new` case *or* the `Object.create` case.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your underscore comment. In your example it would be more convenient for Square to re use the constructor function (Rectangle) or init. `args.width=args.side;args.height=args.side;Rectangle.apply(this,args)` Using an object to pass to a constructor (or a chain of functions that make up a process). You'd call the constructor like `var s = new Square({side:4,x:0,y:0});` With some JSDoc at the constructor it makes the whole thing a lot more readable and easier to pass around arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `budgetSections[0].id = 'yourID';`?