# Working with Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I am Currently Trying to work with JavaScript in a cleaner object orientated way, So Please excuse me if I'm doing this entirely incorrectly I am using **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514645/javascript-prototype-general-enquries-and-assign-id-by-array-index)** previous questions answer as a general reference, but Here's my 'test' code:

```
//Create some sample objects to play with.
var testJSON = {
    "rectangle": [
        { "id":3 , "x":5, "y":10, "width":10, "height":50
        }
    ]
};

//Create Rectangle Constructor
var rectangle = {
  init: function( i, x, y, width, height ) {
    this.id = i,
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.fields = []
  },
  move: function( x, y ) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
  }
};

//Create test array to hold all the objects
var test = [];

//Create a new rectangle object
var myRectangle = Object.create( rectangle );
myRectangle.init( 1, 0, 0, 2, 4 );
myRectangle.move( 3, 5 );

//put rectangle object in array associated with id
test[myRectangle.id] = myRectangle;

//Create a new rectangle object with the same variable name as it will all be in an array anyway.
var myRectangle = Object.create( rectangle );
myRectangle.init( 2, 0, 0, 2, 4 );
myRectangle.move( 0, 0 );

//put rectangle object in array associated with id
test[myRectangle.id] = myRectangle;

//put JSON result in
test[testJSON.rectangle[0].id] = testJSON.rectangle[0];

//No Longer need this variable, is it worth getting rid of.. i dont know
myRectangle =null;

//Try and use methods created in the constructor.
test[2].move(4,8);

console.log(test);
```

Okay, Now the actual questions, The Application I am trying to create, has both json data and it will have users that create data, so for example: the application will generate a bunch of 'rectangles' and then the user can also create rectangles.
 So the first question would be, 'Is this the correct approach' and then secondly how would i get the json data to also have the method defined in the rectangle constructor (move)?

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: json is just for encoding data structures. it's not intended for encoding entire objects with their methods. e.g. it's not a "serialize"-type system.

Comment: Just FYI, the value of the variable `testJSON` is _not_ JSON.  Something can only be JSON if it is a string of a particular syntax.  What you have is just JavaScript, not JSON.  Common mistake. So, so, common....

Comment: `testJSON` isn't even JSON. For example, `{a: "b"}` is not JSON while `"{'a':'b'}"` is.

Comment: Marc B, I understand that, sorry i can see how my question was could have been misinterpreted.. What I meant to ask was basically do i loop through the json data and create objects out of each or?. . . sorry about the json thing i will fix and amend the question.

Answer (score 0):

This an extension of what @Marc B and @Ray Toal mentioned...
You have created javascript functions - which is not at all that bad - but not JSON. To create graphics, you could use the canvas tag as, in effect, a "drawing div" and use the object's x and y positions to constantly update them - if you were considering doing 2d animation. If so, I would recommend [CreateJs](http://www.createjs.com) as a starting block before hard-coding JAVASCRIPT animations. Again, you're code is just fine, but having users create this data - if you were considering a server application would involve using real JSON or perhaps Node.js - but for now I'd focus on single player aspect and setting up you're objects on a graphical 'interface' like `<canvas>`

Comment: Hi and thank you for your input, The triangle is merely test data, no animation required and theres no need for canvas. Its just matter of, there will be predefined html tables (the data will be in json) and then the user will be able to add a html table and so forth. But the user created table and the predefined tables need to both have the same methods.. So What would be the cleanest way to do it? loop through the data and create an object for each? or?..

Comment: yea, just make sure that you can access the different tables using an array or something.

Comment: okay perfect thanks... All i wanted to know, And from this day forth I will never use the word json unless its json... thanks again everyone...